# Keep text entered in another input field to create a list of previous searches via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I have a 'search' box which a user enters text and presses a submit button where it gets passed to where it is needed in the WebGL correctly but I am trying to keep what has been searched to stop users putting in repeats.

Currently I got this:

```
<input id='searchBox' type='text' />
<input id='button' type='submit' value='Search' />
<input id='outputsearch' type='text' value="Previous entries:"  />
<script>
    $( "searchBox" ).return(function() {
        var text = $( this ).text();
        $( "outputsearch" ).val( text );
    });
</script>
```

I attempted to with that script, is there a way to keep that submitted text?

Comment: try select 2 plugin which this logic ,https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$(function(){
   var arr = [];
   $('#button').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      arr.push($('#searchBox').val());
      $('#searchBox').val('');
      $('#outputsearch').val(arr);
   });
});
```

Also i suggest you to follow this markup:

```
<input id='searchBox' type='text' />
<input id='button' type='submit' value='Search' />
<label>
    Previous entries:<input id='outputsearch' type='text' value="" />
</label>
```

#### [Find a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3U5KD/)

Comment: Fantastic! The push on click! Works brilliantly! Thank you so much for replying so fast also. Mark up is also better, can style the "Previous entries:" in my ccs and move it about much more easily. Cheers for help, can understand this so much.